# given the det of a matrix find the det of another matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

> $\begin{vmatrix}
>   a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \\
>   b_1 & b_2 & b_3 \\
>   c_1 & c_2 & c_3 
> \end{vmatrix}=-4$
> Find $\begin{vmatrix}
>   2a_3 & 2a_2 & 2a_1 \\
>   b_3-a_3 & b_2-a_2 & b_1-a_1 \\
>   c_3+3b_3 & c_2+3b_2 & c_1+3b_1
> \end{vmatrix}$.

[image]

I tried to solve this problem by transforming the second matrix to the first one by taking common factors and then multiply the first matrix by the product of the common factors of the second so I took 2 and 3 as common factors but I don't know how to complete my solution

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and [Short and helpful advice on using MathJax on the site …](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33179). (From the edit you can see how you can write determinants.)

Answer (score 2):

Start with the original matrix (call it $A$) and apply the following facts:

$1)$ If you multiply a row (or column) of $A$ by a scalar $c$, then you must multiply the determinant by $c$.

$2)$ Swapping a row (or column) changes the sign of the determinant.

$3)$ Adding a row of $A$ multiplied by a scalar $c$ to another row does not change the determinant.

Answer (score 0):

Given what Stuck said, here are the facts to apply in order

Fact 2,Fact 1, Fact 3, Fact 3.

Also, to Stuck, I hope you don't mind me working off your comment.